# Visual Basic adding to an empty array

Tags: vb.net

I have a string array, I want to add values to it from a List box, it doesn't seem to work however, I don't want to initialise the array with any values and I also don't want to define its size.

```
Public P1_Chosen_Declaration_Powers() As String
```

I want to add the values of checked items in a list box, why does this not work?

```
ListBox.CheckedItems.CopyTo(P1_Chosen_Declaration_Powers, 0)
```

Comment: Is it WinForms? Can't find `CheckedItems` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it takes the array as a parameter ByVal it can't dynamically change the size of your array. You'll need to pass an array that already has the size that is needed. You will need to properly initialize the array, something like this.

```
ReDim P1_Chosen_Declaration_Powers(ListBox.CheckedItems.Count)
```

I would highly suggest you use a List which has a size that is dynamic.

Comment: Would I have to reinitialize the array each time I copy the contents of list box into the array or just once for each function?

Comment: @KonradCzajkowski Every time you call CopyTo, you need to make sure the array contains enough space for the content to be copied.

Comment: Thank you very much, for context, this is part of my coursework for computer science, this project is due in next month so thanks. :)